# JSON inside JSON from SOLR

Tags: json, solr

I have entities defined as documents to get JSON data from SOLR server.

Now Every entity has a group of sub entities which I want in form of a separate JSON object.

However that is not happening

I need

```
[{
  entity: entity
    { [subentities: {

    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solr supports nested documents now (version 4.7+ and improved in 4.8 I think). However the syntax and usage has to follow [Solr specifications](http://heliosearch.org/solr-4-8-features/).

However, you may find that you need to step back and think in the other direction. What are you trying to find? If the information is present in the child record, do you want to find the parent record as well? If so, you may want to flatten the information into the parent record. Solr's goal is to help you find records, not preserve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Solr by itself isn't able to index or provide any useful structure for hierarchical data, such as free form JSON documents. You can attach JSON in a field by itself (stored=true, indexed=false), but that will require you to decode the JSON yourself after your client has processed it.

There is however one project, [SirenDB](http://sirendb.com/), that attempts to enable hierarchical search and processing with JSON on top of Solr. That would allow you to search against the structure of the JSON documents and do more useful processing. Elastic Search might also be suitable, with their [Nested Types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html).

Comment: Old knowledge. Now, Solr does allow nested documents.